# ValueConverter in binding for Polygon Fill property in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, polygon, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to bind Fill property to bool property IsBottomSelected in ModelView using ValueConverter

Here my xaml for polygon:

```
  <Polygon Name="h_bottom" Points="50,50 0,100 100,100 50,50" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="3"  MouseLeftButtonDown="h_bottom_MouseDown" >
        <Polygon.Fill>
            <Binding Path="IsBottomSelected">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <view:BoolToColorConverter/>
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Polygon.Fill>
    </Polygon>
```

and this is ValueConverter:

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

        try
        {

            if (Convert.ToBoolean(value.ToString())) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);

        }

        catch { }

        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

    }



    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The same code is working in WPF, in Silverlight 5 ValueConverter not fired.

Comment: All the code you have here works perfectly, so it is something else. I copied your code into a new Silverlight project and hooked up the `DataContext`, properties, and events. It worked just fine. So, you have to be doing something wrong in the rest of your code. What is `IsBottomSelected`... a `DependencyProperty`?